# background image not showing properly

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position, display

I am trying to set a background image for a header. This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

This is what I am getting:

[image]

So, a tiny weird strip at the bottom end. Here is my code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="header">
          <nav class="cf" id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">FOLK</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">JAZZ</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">SIGNATURE</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">NYLON</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>

      <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
          <img id="rays" src="Images/PNGs/rayons.png">
          <img id="base" src="Images/PNGs/baseLogo.png">
          <img id="roue" src="Images/PNGs/roue.png">
          <img id="letters" src="Images/PNGs/title.png">
        </div>
      </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;

}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("Images/menu.jpg");
    width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 6;
    background-size: 100% 100px;
}
```

I have tried adding a size property to the background, like so:

background-size: 100% 100px;

And that's how I am getting the tiny strip at the bottom. Without that property I get nothing at all. Also, the header is not as long as the page although I have set the width at 100vw. Thanks of your time.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100px; Shouldn't this be 100% 100%?? Not 100% 100px;

Comment: try changing the value of background-size to 100% width and 100% height to stretch it fully. background-size:100% 100%; Also, check if giving it height:10vh would actually give it 10% of your intended container. If so, try changing it to 100vh, see if it affects it then adjust accordingly,

Comment: I tried your code as it is and it displayed properly. It could be your browser displaying oddly. Try running it if different browsers. Also, you have good answers here already. Try them while you are at it.

Answer (score 3):

I made some changes to your header:

```
#header {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  background-image: url("Images/menu.jpg");
  /*width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 6;*/
  background-size:cover;/*added this*/
  padding: 5px;/*added this*/
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sg7dfpzj/

Hope that helps, cheerio!

Answer (score 1):

Remove height for `#header` Class

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("Images/menu.jpg");
    width: 100vw;
    /*height: 10vh;*//*Remove this*/
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 6;
    background-size: 100% 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a padding top and bottom for the header until you have all the image showing, the problem with empty spaces, you dont tell the browser how to show the image,
add some more content or add a padding top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code for the `class="cf"` and `id="menu"` for the line `<nav class="cf" id="menu">` in the `body` section of the HTML code?

There might be an error there. Check it out.